# Fatal Error "Class...not found" on Using Composer Install on CLI

Tags: laravel, composer-php

i'm installing composer for laravel 4, and on hitting `composer install` on the CLI, and on hitting Enter i get the following error/warnings:
`

```
F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master>composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to u
pdate them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider' not found in F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php on line 123
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\artisan:0
PHP   2. require_once() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\artisan:30
PHP   3. require() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\bootstrap\start.php:60
PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Fo
undation\start.php:195
PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Il
luminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:51
PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Ill
uminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:89
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSup
portServiceProvider' not found","file":"F:\\My Documents\\WAMP\\www\\laravel-master\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation
\\ProviderRepository.php","line":123}}Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider' not found in F:\My Documents\WAMP
  \www\laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php on line 123
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\artisan:0
  PHP   2. require_once() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\artisan:30
  PHP   3. require() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\bootstrap\start.php:60
  PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illumina
  te\Foundation\start.php:195
  PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\s
  rc\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:51
  PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider() F:\My Documents\WAMP\www\laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\sr
  c\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:89




install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progre
ss] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

What could be the problem? I've tried searching up everywhere on google but no success.

Comment: If you've updated your app from 4.0 to 4.1, quite a bit changed in terms of the service providers and class aliases. You may find that either you haven't updated something there you should have, or the opposite: that you updated something there before you did the `composer update` and it's broken the 'pre-update' scripts.

Comment: mmhh so now what can i do, because even `composer update` gives an error?

Comment: You could try `composer update --no-scripts` which will not try to run any Laravel stuff on update. And then once you're updated, see if things like artisan work. If not, you'll still have to manually check that all your bits are done (providers and aliases are you biggest bit, but there's also the `bootstrap/start.php` file).

Comment: i succeeded. this is what i did:
1. i enabled `openssl` on the 2 `php.ini` files in the `bin/apache` and `bin/php` folders of my WAMP.
2. i was initially using Internet with proxy. I switched to modem and my woes were over. This was the main reason for the success.
i hope all this helps somebody

Comment: Woah that seems like a right faff!

Comment: If you solved your problem then please [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that it doesn't appear as unanswered anymore.

Comment: thanks @André, i have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i succeeded. this is what i did: 1. i enabled openssl on the 2 php.ini files in the bin/apache and bin/php folders of my WAMP. 2. i was initially using Internet with proxy. I switched to modem and my woes were over. This was the main reason for the success. i hope all this helps somebody